# My lifecycle codes not compiling

Tags: java, android

For each callback events (onCreate(), onStart()... ), record what callback event was triggered in the log(use Log.d); the message that is written to log should be defined in “strings.xml” and getResources.getString() should be used to retrieve the message

Implement onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState – to track the number of times onSaveInstanceState is being called, in onRestoreInstanceState, print the value to the log file

Tag for “Log” statement should also be defined in strings.xml and set using getResources.getString()

```
package com.csci235labs.rob_lifecycles;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String TAG = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name); //Logcat tag
String ActivityState;
int instanceTimes; //number of times instance is called
String Act_keys;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //recover instance state
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        ActivityState = savedInstanceState.getString(Act_keys);
    }
    else
    {
        instanceTimes=0;
        Act_keys="";
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    instanceTimes++;
    ActivityState=String.valueOf(instanceTimes);

    outState.putString(Act_keys,ActivityState);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //logs event message
    String eventMessage=getResources().getString(R.string.on_start_str);
    Log.d(TAG,eventMessage);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //logs event message
    String eventMessage=getResources().getString(R.string.on_resume_str);
    Log.d(TAG,eventMessage);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //logs event message
    String eventMessage=getResources().getString(R.string.on_pause_str);
    Log.d(TAG,eventMessage);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    //logs event message
    String eventMessage=getResources().getString(R.string.on_stop_str);
    Log.d(TAG,eventMessage);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //logs event message
    String eventMessage=getResources().getString(R.string.on_destroy_str);
    Log.d(TAG,eventMessage);
 }
}
```

XML File:

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">rob_lifecycles</string>
  <string name="app_str">teststring</string>
  <string name="on_create_str">onCreate() method</string>
  <string name="on_start_str">onStart() method</string>
  <string name="on_resume_str">onResume() method</string>
  <string name="on_pause_str">onPause() method</string>
  <string name="on_stop_str">onStop() method</string>
  <string name="on_destroy_str">onDestroy() method</string>
  <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: You should edit your question with the XML code.

Comment: Also, what errors do you get? And which lines cause them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the TAG initialization outside and move it to onCreate() because context.getResources() will give null pointer exception in that case

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String TAG;
String ActivityState;
int instanceTimes; //number of times instance is called
String Act_keys;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TAG = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name); //Logcat tag
    //recover instance state
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
       ActivityState = savedInstanceState.getString(Act_keys);
    }
    else
    {
       instanceTimes=0;
       Act_keys="";
    }
}
```

Comment: if this worked for you, don't forget to accept the answer @Rob